# Authlogic validation order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

guys. I have a problem when doing the authlogic login validation. I have the magical "active" field in the user model, say if active is false, when login with correct password, it will pop up the message like "You are suspended, please contact your administration" (I defined this message in I18n file); when login with wrong password, it will pop up the the not_active message plus password_invalid message like "password invalid". I think that is because authlogic did the validation both for "active" field and password and it seems password validation comes first.

My question is, how can bypass the password validation if 'active' is false. Or, can I only show not_active message? my code like:

```
if @user_session.save
  redirect_to home_path
else
  render :json => {:success => false, :error => @user_session.errors.full_messages.join("\n")}
end
```

Comment: I think you should first check for password and then for active.

Comment: @Joy: But I want to bypass the password validation if active is false. I just want to show the not_active message if the user is inactive, without the password_invalid message no matter right or wrong password user inputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I don't like this as a user-experience, but if you really want to, do something like:

```
before_filter :restrict_inactive_users, :on=>:create

def restrict_inactive_users
  @user = User.find_by_login(params[:user_session][:login]) rescue nil
  return unless @user
  unless @user.active?
    flash[:error] = "You are suspended, please contact your administration"
    render :action=>:new
    return false 
  end
end

def create
  @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
  if @user_session.save
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    render :json => {:success => false, :error =>   @user_session.errors.full_messages.join("\n")}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, this solution is easy to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Today I thought out a solution which doesn't bypass the password validation but just delete the password error message from user_session. Code like:

```
if @user_session.save
  redirect_to home_path
else
  @user_session.errors.delete(:password) unless @user_session.attempted_record.active
  render :json => {:success => false, :error => @user_session.errors.full_messages.join("\n")}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with fetching the user by the identifier of your choice, like the email or user name. 
If the user is not active you can remove the other errors before redirecting back to the login page.

```
        @user_session.errors.clear
```

Then the errors will not show when the page is rerendered. But you must provide a custom error message, for example via the `flash.now[:error]` or your json response.